# functions that can be written as $g^3$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a proper sub-domain of $\mathbb{C}$ in which every everywhere
nonzero function $f$ can be written as $g^3$ with $g$ being holomorphic,
then show that there is a holomorphic embedding of $D$ into the
unit disc.

Can one please provide some hint ? I'm stuck on it for a long time

Comment: Show that $D$ must be simply connected: Assume it is not and construct a function without cubic root. Since it is simply connected and proper you can map it to the unit disc.

Comment: @Alamos I think he is not allowed to use riemann mapping theorem since generally this is the first step in the proof of riemann mapping theorem

Comment: Never seen a proof using cubes.

Comment: @Potato Go ahead and try the plane minus the origin.

Comment: I don't get how to show $D$ is simply connected ??

Comment: @Alamos modified the standard proof using squareroots for cube roots have a look at it and let me know if something is wrong

Comment: @dragoboy If it is not simply connected you don't have cubic roots for a function that vanishes at a point $z_0\notin D$ that is surrounded by $D$, say $z-z_0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since we can define cuberoots in this domain Consider the function $f(z)=z-a$ where $a$ is a complex number which is not in $D$ . This ensures that the function is non zero everywhere and hence has a cuberoot.

Call this cuberoot function $r(z)$. So $r(z)$ satisfies $r(z)^3=z-a$. Now clearly $r(z)$ cannot assume the value both $w$ and $we^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$. Since that will mean $w^3$ has no unique image.

By open mapping theorem we know that there is an open ball around $w'=we^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ which is not contained in the image. So $|r(z)-w'|>\delta$. Now $\frac{\delta}{r(z)-w'}$ is the required embedding